# Is it possible in git-tfs to add tfs branch/project as additional remote?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I have to work with a messed-up TFS repository. By messed-up I mean the following:

```
--|- Dev branch ---------|------
  |                      |
 previous branching    new branching
 to release            to release
  |                      |
  |                      |
   -- Release branch --* --------
                       |
                 branch deletion
```

As you can see, the branching policies are a little bit questionable...

So, my TFS branch was created from *Dev branch* somewhere between *previous branching* and the *new* one, using **quick-clone**(and **quick** is due to other messed-up branches). Now I have to synchronize my changes between these two branches (*Dev* and *Release*) and, obviously, I cannot **branch --init** the *Release* branch.

(Attempt to clone the whole repository again with branches did not succeed because of the weirdness of the TFS repository management)

There are two options I am currently aware of:

1. Resort to TFS for merging
2. Clone an additional git repository from the *Release* branch and add this repository as a remote to my repository following the *Dev*. This will result in continuing working with GIT, but I'm not sure it is worth the effort because of additional overhead of synchronizing the new repository separately.

One other possibility I can think of is addition of the *Dev* branch as additional remote directly to my current repository. However, I didn't find any way to do it.

My question is whether the above is possible and, in case it isn't, are there any other sane alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the case n°2 will work. 
Quickclone the dev branch in a new repository, then add this repository as a remote just the time to fetch the changeset (you could delete the repository after). 
Then you could Fetch and rcheckin from here.

Ps: which version do you use? The last will be better. If you did 2 'quickclone' for each of the branches, there is an option in the config file to change to better manage branches (I will try to find it's name because I didn't remember and I have not documented it :-( )

Ps2: if you didn't Fetch a merge changeset, git won't help you a lot during merges...

Ps3: There is some restrictions on doing merges with git-tfs: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md#merge-2-branches-and-checkin-this-merge-in-tfs

I hope it will help...

Comment: Tried it, got a StackOverflowException on *fetch* while it tried to get the *Dev* branch as related. Looks like I'm back to TFS here... Thank you for the suggestion, though.